# Output of Code is all Zeros

Tags: c, arrays, file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

float tolGap(float Tol[], int size);
float meanGap(float Nom[], float Imp[], int size);
void parsePart(char input[], float *pNom, int *pImp, float *pTol, char* pFoV);
void parseGap(char input[], float *max, float *min);

int main()
{
    FILE *pIN;
    int i;
    int Impact[10];
    float Nominal[10], Tolerance[10];
    char FoV[10];
    char input_str[30];
    float max, min, tol;
    int Num_of_Parts;
    float curr_max, curr_min, mean;

    pIN=fopen("testingcode.txt", "r");

    for(i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
        fgets(input_str,30, pIN);
        if(input_str[0] == 'p')
        {
            parsePart(input_str, &Nominal[i], &Impact[i], &Tolerance[i], &FoV[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            parseGap(input_str, &min, &max);
            Num_of_Parts = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    mean = meanGap(Nominal, Impact, Num_of_Parts);
    tol = tolGap(Tolerance, Num_of_Parts);
    curr_max = mean+tol;
    curr_min = mean - tol;

    if (fabs(max - curr_max) < 0.00001) //they are equal
    {
        printf("The Maximum Gap (%fin) is equal to specified (%fin)\n", max, curr_max);
    }

    if ((max - curr_max) > 0.00001)
    {
        printf("The Maximum Gap (%fin) is Greater than specified (%fin)\n", max, curr_max);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The Maximum Gap (%fin) is within specified (%fin)\n", max, curr_max);
    }

    if (fabs(min - curr_min) < 0.00001) //they are equal
    {
        printf("The Minimum Gap (%fin) is equal to specified (%fin)\n", min, curr_min);
    }

    if ((min - curr_min) > 0.00001)
    {
        printf("The Minimum Gap (%fin) is Greater than specified (%fin)\n", min, curr_min);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The Minimum Gap (%fin) is Less than specified (%fin)\n", min, curr_min);
    }

    return 0;
}

float tolGap(float Tol[], int size)
{
    int i;
    float sum=0;

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        sum+=Tol[i];
    }
    printf("Actual Gap Tolerance: %fin\n", sum);
    return sum;
}

float meanGap(float Nom[], float Imp[], int size)
{
    int i;
    float sum=0;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        sum+= Nom[i]*Imp[i];
    }
    printf("Actual Gap Mean: %fin\n", sum);
    return sum;
}

void parsePart(char input[], float *pNom, int *pImp, float *pTol, char* pFoV)
{
    int i;
    char *elements[5];

    elements[0]=strtok(input, ",");

    for(i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
        elements[i] = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    *pNom = atof(elements[1]);
    *pImp = atoi(elements[2]);
    *pTol = atof(elements[3]);
    *pFoV = *elements[4];

}

void parseGap(char input[], float *max, float *min)
{
    int i;
    char *elements[5];

    elements[0]=strtok(input, ",");

    for(i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
        elements[i] = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    *max = atof(elements[1]);
    *min = atof(elements[2]);
}
```

My File has this information contained within it:

```
PART,2.000,-1,0.050,V

PART,0.975,-1,0.025,V

PART,3.000,+1,0.010,F

GAP,0.000,0.080
```

In the file there are no blank lines, I added them for clarity. The issue is that none of my calculations are being done. All of my outputs come to be 0.000000. I want it to actually calculate it but can't find the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you used a debugger?

Comment: my program did not come with one. Should it have or do I need to download one?

Comment: What OS, compiler and IDE (if any) are you using?

Comment: Codeblocks on Windows. I know Codeblocks has a debugger but maybe I downloaded the wrong version perhaps. Edit: I checked and it says I have the debugger but all my options for running the debugger are grey and inactive except for the debugging windows button

Comment: You need to invoke your compiler with warnings enabled. If you do it will find a type mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an array of `int`s

```
int Impact[10];

...

mean = meanGap(Nominal, Impact, Num_of_Parts);
```

to a function expecting an array of `float`s

```
float meanGap(float Nom[], float Imp[], int size)
```

---

You are wriitng outside the bounds of arrays:

```
int Impact[10];
float Nominal[10], Tolerance[10];
char FoV[10];
...

for(i=0; i<11; i++)
```

should be

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
```

---

And as pointed out by @user2340048, `PART` is in uppercase and you are checking for `p` in `if(input_str[0] == 'p')`

Comment: I thought the reason to keep it at 11 would be so that it stores the \0 character at the end of the array and then can hold 10 other numbers in the array. I changed the first array to be: float Impact[10] but still have the same issue.

Comment: I don't know the reason but there is an access out of bounds (because you don't check the result of `fgets` and your parse function is executed  11 times)

Answer (score 0):

The following line:
if(input_str[0] == 'p') should be replaced with:
if(input_str[0] == 'P') since in the data file, the 'PART' is in uppercase but you are checking for lowercase 'p'.

Comment: did not change my outputs unfortunately. However, that is good to know that the character it searches for is case-sensitive.